# Why Entity Framework services are not running when publishing?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

We're having two systems that are in LAN. Database is in one system
and published files are in another system. Through code the connection is opening
and getting the results, but at publishing time getting "400 Bad Request Error".

If the system having Database, iis in one system at published time also running the 
services successfully. But if database is in one system and iis is in another system
then at published time the services are not running.

Please tell me what is the reason and how to resolve that?

Comment: Is this a standard WCF service or is this ADO.NET Data Services? Are the two machines in the same domain?

Comment: yea they are at same domain.Standard WCF Service..